# Header: no number for references page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How can I make sure that the references page has no number in the header (i. e., I still want a header, but without a number).

[image]

MWE with the problem:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{section}>0  \thesection. \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\section{Example}

\clearpage

\renewcommand{\thepage}{}


\begin{thebibliography}{99}


\end{thebibliography} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new page style, say, `bib` like

```
\fancypagestyle{bib}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
   \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
```

without the section number and then just before `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` issue `\pagestyle{bib}`

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{section}>0  \thesection. \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

%%% this is not needed as this does nothing. plain page style is exactly this one.
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{
%  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%  \fancyhf{}
%  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%}

\fancypagestyle{bib}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
   \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\section{Example}

\clearpage

%\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
\pagestyle{bib}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}


\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't think you completely understood what I wanted. What I want is that the `1.` in the header of the references page disappears (the 1 that is circled in the image in the OP).

Comment: Ah, I see you updated it now, I'll have a look, thanks :)!

Comment: This does what I wanted, thank you for your help :)!